# Why Custom Validators cannot be applied to field which does not contains any value?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am just a bit stuck with Custom Validation. I have created a web page under which I have applied custom Validation on different fields like firstName, LastName etc...However, when I try to apply custom validation on a field which does not contains any value, the custom validation does not get fired, whether it is on Client Side or Server Side. I tried to find the answer to this as to why this was happening and I came to know that Custom Validation cannot be applied to field which does not contains any value.

However, this can be done with Required Field Validator.

I want to achieve that if First Name and Last Name are entered by the User, then they should enter Address too, making it mandatory. When I tried custom Validation on Address textbox, it does not get fired. Please help

Comment: could you paste what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ValidateEmptyText` property to true.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx